# Responsive images with <picture> and <source> in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to achieve HTML-"art direction" (displaying different images for different viewport widths) in React. This is the JSX:

```
import LogoImg from "../../abstracts/media/logo-large.svg";
import LogoImgMedium from "../../abstracts/media/logo-medium.svg";

<picture>
   <source srcSet={`${LogoImgMedium} 1x, ${LogoImg} 2x`} media="(max-width: 37.5em)" />
   <img 
      className="logo__apple" 
      srcSet={`${LogoImgMedium} 1x, ${LogoImg} 2x`} 
      alt="Full Logo"
      src={LogoImgMedium} />
 </picture>
```

The breakpoint defined in the `media` attribute does not seem to work. Do you guys know why? I have tried to specify it with px, rem and em.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just specified the same value in `srcSet` attributes of `source` and `img` elements, which will display the same image for all widths. This might vary, but the browser is more likely to select the medium image in that case.

To display medium image for small screens and large image, just change:

```js
<picture>
   <source srcSet={`${LogoImgMedium} 1x, ${LogoImg} 2x`} media="(max-width: 37.5em)" />
   <img 
      className="logo__apple" 
      srcSet={`${LogoImgMedium} 1x, ${LogoImg} 2x`} 
      alt="Full Logo"
      src={LogoImgMedium} />
 </picture>
```

to:

```js
<picture>
  <source srcSet={`${LogoImgMedium} 1x`} media="(max-width: 500px)" />
  <img
    className="logo__apple"
    srcSet={`${LogoImg} 2x`}
    alt="Full Logo" />
</picture>;
```